# how to pass user defined params to facebook messenger bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to pass a custom params in postback call so could anyone please suggest me how to send custom params below is my code:-

```
 buttons:[{
        type: "postback",
        title: p.name,
        payload: "get_product" }]
```

but I wanted to pass custom params to payload or button array.

```
payload: '{:payload => "get_product", :product_id => "#{p.id}" }'
```

but this code is not working.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Only single payload string will be return. So concat the params into single string (eg: "get_product|id")